# Обработка сообщений ВКонтакте Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть бот ВК на Python 3. Используется библиотека vk_api.
Предположим, есть такой код:

```
bot_longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id) # получаю longpoll api
vk = vk_session.get_api()
for event in bot_longpoll.listen(): # слушаю longpoll
   if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
       if event.object.text == f'Ник Пользователь':
           vk.messages.send(random_id=random.getrandbits(32), peer_id=event.object.peer_id,
                         message='тут чтот-то надо писать')
```

В чем суть? event.object.text - это ВСЁ (его содержание) сообщение от пользователя, который написал "Ник Пользователь", можно ли сделать так, чтобы бот не проверял слово ник в evente и проверял только Пользователь (сам ник)? Если да, то можно, пожалуйста, способы реализации этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `event.object.text.lower().split()`

Первая функция будет менять регистр на нижний, а вторая будет разделять слова по пробелу.

Например:

```py
words = event.object.text.lower().split()
if words[1] == 'username':
    pass # что-то делается
```

Про `split` почитайте [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), а про `lower` [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

Comment: Спасибо, бот теперь отвечает на команды, если добавить слов. Вот теперь такой вопрос: можно ли сохранить в какую-нибудь переменную слова, что идут после слова "ник"?

Comment: Можно. Это уже другой вопрос. Изучайте питон, пожалуйста, на курсах или по документации.